# Pass Json array into different html divs

Tags: php, html, json, ajax

I want to use the first 3 result of my Json array in 3 different divs.

The array returned from ajax.php look like this:

```
'{"res":["106"],"base":["190220"]}'
```

So I want the first value "res":["106"] in the div id: Response1 and "base":["190220"] in the div id : Response2.
My knowledge of this is only 1% so I need some help from you guys :)

html and ajax:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<form id="resource">
    <input type="number" id="base" name="base" placeholder="Base ID" value="170143" />
    <input type="number" id="lot" name="lot" placeholder="Lot ID" value="110"/>
</form>

<div id="response1"></div>

<div id="response2"></div>

<div id="response3"></div>

<script src="../vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    (function($){
        function processForm( e ){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'ajax.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                type: 'post',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function( data ){
                    $('#response1').html( data );
                    console.log( data );
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        $('#resource').change( processForm );
    })(jQuery);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here my ajax.php file:

```
<?php
require_once('background.php');

if(isset($_POST['base']) and isset($_POST['lot'])){  
    $base = $_POST['base'];    
    $lot = $_POST['lot']; 

    $baseSql = "SELECT * FROM QBS_ABL_VMSCHRP1_SIM where WORKORDER_BASE_ID = '".$base."' AND WORKORDER_LOT_ID = '".$lot."'";
    $baseSTH = $pdo->prepare($baseSql);
    $baseSTH->execute();

    while($row = $baseSTH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $resArray['res'][] = $row['RESOURCE_ID'];
        $resArray['base'][] = $row['WORKORDER_BASE_ID'];
    }

    if(isset($resArray)){
        json_encode($resArray);
    }  
}

?>
```

Comment: try changing your "dataType: 'html'," to "dataType: 'json',"

Comment: @JulyanoFelipe Already did.

Comment: "and so on" becomes unclear after your last edit, there is only one value in `"res"`. To help us understand what your problem is, what are you currently getting in your div?

Comment: You should probably return/echo something back in your `ajax.php`

Comment: @Kaddath ah sorry. edited the post to make it clear. im getting nothing in my div when I use `json_encode($resArray);` `var_dump(json_encode($resArray))` result: `'{"res":["106"],"base":["190220"]}'`

Comment: Use your browsers dev tools Network tab to see if the response of `ajax.php` is actually the JSON you are expecting - or if it is empty since you don't return anything from `ajax.php`

Comment: @kerbholz The response from the network tab is perfect. I see both values in the array from ajax.php

Comment: I got what I want! however the output in the div is = ["106"] and ["190220"]. How can I display it just as 106 and 190220?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by changing this:

```
(function($){
    function processForm( e ){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'post',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function( data, textStatus ){
                res = (data['res']);
                base = (data['base']);
                $('#response1').html( res );
                $('#response2').html( base );
                //console.log( data );
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#resource').change( processForm );
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `JSON.stringify` on `data['res']` and `data['base']`, they are strings already.